# How to dynamically update ng-style based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I want to pass on the value of **x**, **y** from the array (item.x, item.y) to the `ng-style` of the parent element by updating the variables `transformX`, `transformY` (the updating is achieved by `ng-click` directive).

-html-

```
<section ng-style="{'transform' : translate(transformX,transformY)}">
  <figure ng-repeat="item in items" 
          style="left: {{item.x}}px; top: {{item.y}}px;"
          ng-click="$parent.transformX = item.x * -1; 
                    $parent.transformY = item.y * -1;">
    {{item.title}}
  </figure>
</section>
```

-controller-

```
$scope.transformX = 0;
$scope.transformY = 0;

$scope.items = [

  { title: "foo",
    x: 50,
    y: -20
  }

  ,{ title: "bar",
    x: -40,
    y: 10
  }
];
```

This is what I can't achieve - I want the parent element's (`section`) style attribute to update with the click on the `figure` child element so that the clicked item is centered (hence `item.y * -1`). The variable does update, the style doesn't.

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/3izwAEvyjk6JOhahKx0w?p=preview)

Is there any way to make `transformX`and `transformY` variables inside `ng-style` directive to actually work and dynamically update? This `ng-style="{'transform' : translate(transformX,transformY)}"` doesn't work..

Comment: Haven't quite understood what you're trying to achieve... is this better ? http://plnkr.co/edit/byFiZ445Ci4VjdlmiLcX?p=preview

Comment: @OmriAharon I've updated the question so I hope it's more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, it would just end up with the very last item.x and item.y variables. So if this is your goal you could just do this

```
    transformX = items[items.length - 1].x
```

and

```
    transformY = items[items.length - 1].y
```

This is because there is only ever going to be one section element in the html. If you want the transform variables to have each of the x and y variables you need to put the ng-repeat up a level in the section tag.